# it is surjective - $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}: x \rightarrow 2x$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

i think, this function is surjective:
$$f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}: x \rightarrow 2x$$

but in my textbook it says, it is not surjective. but no proof there. i am really wondering if it is a mistake. because for all $y\in\mathbb{N}$ it is true that $f^{-1}\{y\}\neq \emptyset$. for example: $2,4,6,8,10,12,..$ for $y$ there are $1,2,3,4,5,6..$ for $x$.

am i missing here something or what is happening here which makes this not surjective? thanks for help.

Comment: What do you think is a preimage of $1$?

Comment: well, $1$ is outside of function definition, because $y$ is $2x$, isnot it?

Comment: What is $f^{-`1}(3)$?

Comment: Surjective means the function should hit every number in the co-domain, which is $\mathbb{N}$. Can your function map a natural number to $1$?

Comment: but what function defines are even numbers, why should i think about odd numbers?? :(

Comment: This function is injective, not surjective. The function definition is $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, not $f:\mathbb{N}\to2\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @doniyor It does not define the even numbers, nor is it only defined on the even numbers! It maps the naturals onto the naturals. Only the even elements are "hit" on the right side. Therefore, it is not surjective.

Comment: @Cbenni, yeahh, now i got it. so i should look at domain and co-domain to see if EVERY element from these domains are hit, right?

Comment: @doniyor (continued) Especially, you are doing something very wrong here: You say for all elements of the naturals $f^{-1}(\{y\})\neq \emptyset$, but that is straight wrong, you "prove" it by taking only the elements of $2\mathbb{N}$. Of course, the function is surjective from $\mathbb{N}\to 2\mathbb{N}$, however that is not the case.

Comment: @Cbenni, exactly that was my problem. now i got it. great help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is surjective if for every $y\in Y$ there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Here, there is no natural number that is mapped to $1$.

Your confusion might have arisen because you have mixed up the expression for the image of the function ($2x$) with the codomain ($N$).

Comment: yeah Jason, exactly, that was my problem. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective if and only if for every $b\in B$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

In our case, $f(n)\neq 1$ for all $n$, because $1$ is not an even integer and cannot be written as $2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$. Therefore $f$ is not surjective because the codomain is $\mathbb N$, and $1\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

You say that $f^{-1}(\{y\})\not=\varnothing$ for all $y\in\mathbb{N}$, but what is
$$f^{-1}(\{1\})\text{,}$$
since the set $f(\mathbb{N})$ is constituted entirely in even numbers ?

However, note that the same function, but defined on $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is surjective. This is probably what misled you.